# AEM i18n vs MSM

Tags: internationalization, adobe, aem, wcm

AEM supports internationalization using mixin types (i18n). Also there is feature of MSM where we can build a blue print and create sites for various locales using it.

How are these 2 options different and which one to choose when?

Answer (score 5):

Both **i18n ([ResourceBundle](http://sling.apache.org/site/internationalization-support.html))** and **MSM** are required to create a true multilingual website. They work as a team.

MSM provides common structure and content. Say a blueprint has 4 pages , it ensures all language copies will have these 4 pages with same content. How is it different from a regular copy ? **Rollout configs** !

Say you have a navigation bar on the home page. If you did a plain copy of the site's 4 pages under a language page , the links on nav bar of  copied home page would still point point to the original location. With rollout the links will get rewritten to point to the corresponding site's pages.

Also with plain copy , you will have to change common data for every language copy manually. With rollout changes to blueprint cascades to all language copies . So with MSM changes to common stuff like logos , brand messages are done on blueprint. Local data like contact person is done at a language level.

**i18n** is simply used for translation of common words like menu , learn more etc.. In the blue print copy instead of directly writing menu , menu will be put into a fmt:message tag. Sling will then automatically guess the language based on site structure and translate it